# Regex match and get string by pattern JAVA

Tags: java, regex, string

I have here a pattern for email

`Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[A-Za-z0-9+_.-]+@(.+)$");`

also i have a String contains messages

`String message = "Han hannibal@domain.com im 20 years old, i just came here to say nothing..";`

my problem is when matching pattern to string i get nothing. here what i do

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(message);

if(m.find()) {
    Log.d("TAG", m.group(1));
}else {
    Log.d("TAG", "No email found on string");
}
```

i don't if my code was right but i just simply follow some article on fetching words on string using regex.

Comment: since its for android,why not use android inbuilt email address validation. android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(input string).matches();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the anchors from your regex.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b[A-Za-z0-9+_.-]+@(?:[^.\\s]+\\.)+\\w{2,4}\\b");
```

**Example:**

```
String message = "Han hannibal@domain.com im 20 years old, i just came here to say nothing..";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b[A-Za-z0-9+_.-]+@(?:[^.\\s]+\\.)+\\w{2,4}\\b");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(message);
if(m.find())
{
    System.out.println("TAG " + m.group());
}

else {
    System.out.println("TAG " + "No email found on string");
}
```

**Output:**

```
TAG hannibal@domain.com
```

Comment: by the way, i forgot is this work also on android? coz android is java base right?

Comment: @AvinashRaj can we continue on chat? if have time. :) i got i more thing to ask :) hahaha

Comment: Allowing only 2-4 characters for TLD is simply behind the time. There are many new generic TLD with more than 4 characters. Heck, there are even internationalized TLD.

Comment: yep, this would work for simpler case. For  complex cases, he may consider reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)